# Build LIVE555 RTSP Library in a clean directory

Tags: iphone, ios6, live555

Hi I'm wondering how to build the LIVE555 library in a new directory. My current method involves manually deleting the .o and configuration files, and I don't think thats very effective or smart.

Currently my workflow is:

```
./genMakeFiles iphoneos
make
```

But it builds it all in the same directory and it's so messy, can someone shine some light on an attribute I can change in configuration that will build the binaries and header files in a clean directory?

Thank you!

Comment: I got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13928131/940096) issue. Have you faced this before? If yes then, please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 'clean' output with only libs and includes, then you have to modify build script. I'm not very good in writing scripts, but anyway - you may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492031/building-live555-library-for-iphoneos) and download already built libs with includes(link to zip in the last comment). The libs are `fat`, so they contains `i386`, `x86_64`, `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64`.

For adding everything into the Xcode project you have to specify `OTHER_LDFLAGS`:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.a"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/liveMedia/libliveMedia.a"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/groupsock/libgroupsock.a"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a"
```

and `HEADER_SEARCH_PATH`:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/UsageEnvironment/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/liveMedia/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/groupsock/include"
"$(SRCROOT)/<path to live555>/BasicUsageEnvironment/include"
```

And that is all. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose where to install include, libraries and executable setting the PREFIX variable (like the -prefix option of configure) like this :

```
make install PREFIX=<install root>
```

In order to remove *.o, *.a and executable just use :

```
make clean
```