# building live555 library for iphoneos

Tags: ios, build, streaming, live555, rtm

I read a lot of discussions about building live555 lib for iOS platform. I successfully built lib for simulator using `./genMakefiles iphone-simulator` and then `make`, but can not build it for device. `./genMakefiles iphoneos` did not warn me about anything, but running `make` after it fails. It always produces error like `unknown type name …`. I tried many times with freshest sources, and I also tried to `make clean` before doing make - not helped.

From the log I see some weird stuff, like path to `MacOSX`, and I think that this is the root of the problem, but not sure what should I fix/change in the script to make it work.
Here is complete log:

```
$ make
cd liveMedia ; /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
/usr/bin/xcrun clang -c -Iinclude -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include -I.  -DBSD=1 -O2 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -arch armv7 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.2.sdk -Wall Media.cpp
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:75:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:680:2: error: 
      Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:78:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint64_t'
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint16_t'
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: 
      unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:81:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h:37:2: error: 
      architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from Media.cpp:21:
In file included from include/Media.hh:33:
In file included from ../UsageEnvironment/include/UsageEnvironment.hh:28:
In file included from ../groupsock/include/NetCommon.h:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:95:9: error: 
      unknown type name 'u_int64_t'
typedef u_int64_t               u_quad_t;       /* quads */
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [Media.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I hope somebody can help me with solving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could install Xcode command line tool first. Then redo everything for building live555. It's work for me. Just type "xcode-select --install" in your terminal to installation.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Your answer helped me! After I run `xcode-select --install` - scripts worked like a charm!

Comment: For anybody facing the same issue, or any other - here is the link to built libs using Xcode 6.3 (6D570)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8079242/live555-Apr15.2015.zip